# Neural network evaluate on multiple gpus simultaneously

Tags: neural-networks, gpu

For instance, I have 4 gpus, now I want to calculate neural network on each gpu simultaneously, or make use of all of my gpus to calculate the data.

The code might like

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10000, 10}];
net1 = NetInitialize@NetChain[{LinearLayer[{}], LogisticSigmoid}, "Input" -> {10}];
net2 = NetInitialize@NetChain[{LinearLayer[{}], LogisticSigmoid}, "Input" -> {10}];
net3 = NetInitialize@NetChain[{LinearLayer[{}], LogisticSigmoid}, "Input" -> {10}];
net4 = NetInitialize@NetChain[{LinearLayer[{}], LogisticSigmoid}, "Input" -> {10}];

{net1[data, TargetDevice -> {"GPU", 1}], 
 net2[data, TargetDevice -> {"GPU", 2}], 
 net3[data, TargetDevice -> {"GPU", 3}], 
 net4[data, TargetDevice -> {"GPU", 4}]}
```

Is this code make the neural network calculate simultaneously? Is there any way to realize this idea?

I have tried `net1[data,TargetDevice->{"GPU",All}]`, but it returned the message
`NetChain::nomultisupp: Net evaluation is not currently supported with TargetDevice -> {GPU, All}.` In `NetTrain` we can set `TargetDeivce->{"GPU",All}`, why there cannot?

---

### Update

Edmund's method is a right way to distribute jobs to multi-GPUs, I have tested it on my linux system with four GPUs. Here's the test record.

First, launch 4 local kernels and prepare the data

```
LaunchKernels[4];
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10000000, 10}];
```

Second, initialize the network

```
nets = NetInitialize@{
 NetChain[{LinearLayer[{}], LogisticSigmoid},"Input" -> {10}],
 NetChain[{LinearLayer[{}], LogisticSigmoid},"Input" -> {10}],
 NetChain[{LinearLayer[{}], LogisticSigmoid},"Input" -> {10}],
 NetChain[{LinearLayer[{}], LogisticSigmoid},"Input" -> {10}]};
```

Then use the parallel functions, I prefer to use `ParallelEvaluate`, and Edmund's method is okay. In my test (4 1080Ti), the time cost roughly 16s.

```
l = ParallelEvaluate[
 nets[[$KernelID]][data,TargetDevice ->{"GPU",$KernelID}]
];//AbsoluteTiming
```

You can compare with sequentially calculate

```
{nets[[1]][data, TargetDevice -> {"GPU", 1}], 
 nets[[2]][data, TargetDevice -> {"GPU", 2}], 
 nets[[3]][data, TargetDevice -> {"GPU", 3}], 
 nets[[4]][data, TargetDevice -> {"GPU", 4}]}//AbsoluteTiming
```

and use the shell command `nvidia-smi` to see whether four GPUs are working simultaneously. The time cost is roughly 42s, you can see it almost 2.5 times slower than use 4 GPUs together.

Last I found that it's essential to launch kernels before initialize the networks, if you exchange the order, there's a bug report like

```
OMP: Error #13: Assertion failure at z_Linux_util.cpp(2338).
OMP: Hint Please submit a bug report with this message, compile and run commands used, and machine configuration info including native compiler and operating system versions. Faster response will be obtained by including all program sources. For information on submitting this issue, please see http://www.intel.com/software/products/support/.
SubKernels`SubKernels::timekernels: Timeout for subkernels. Received only 0 of 4 connections.
```

So, anyone who knows why?

Comment: Are you asking if WL supports anything similar to TensorFlow [distributed training](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training) I believe the answer is no.

Comment: Take care becuase `$KernelId` will only span 1 to 4 if on the first call of `LaunchKernels[4]` l. If something happens and you need to kill and restart a kernel then your code will fail as at least one kernel will have an id greater than 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`ParallelSubmit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelSubmit.html) and [`WaitAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WaitAll.html).

With `data` and `net*`'s as defined in OP.

Create a set of parallel jobs with `ParallelSubmit`. I only have 1 GPU so I set the others to `"CPU"`.

```
jobs =
 ReleaseHold[
  Map[
   ParallelSubmit
   , Hold[{
     net1[data, TargetDevice -> {"GPU", 1}]
     , net2[data, TargetDevice -> "CPU"]
     , net3[data, TargetDevice -> "CPU"]
     , net4[data, TargetDevice -> "CPU"]
     }]
   , {2}
   ]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The [`Hold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold.html) is necessary to prevent the nets from evaluating in serial in [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html). [`ReleaseHold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReleaseHold.html) removes `Hold`; `ParallelSubmit` has [`HoldAllComplete`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAllComplete.html) so the nets will not evaluate within them.

Then execute with `WaitAll`.  You will see the job objects update their status as they run.

```
res = WaitAll[jobs];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you bro, your method works well, and save much of my time. Very thanks~